# Java getText of looped multiple JTextFields

Tags: java, for-loop, jtextfield, user-input, getter

My first question here. Already got a lot of help but now I don't know how to do.

My code:

```
package view;
```

import javax.swing.*;

public class OptionPlayerNames {

```
JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel();
JTextField playerNames = new JTextField();

public OptionPlayerNames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
```

//          JTextField playerNames = new JTextField();

`playerPanel.add(new JLabel("Player " + (i + 1)));
        playerPanel.add(playerNames);

    }
    playerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(playerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    playerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));


}
public JPanel getPanel(){
    return playerPanel;
}

public String getPlayerNames() {

    return playerNames.getText();

}`

I want to have 8 Jlabels with just under it 8 JTextFields for user input.
Then get the text of the textfields.
Now I get only 1 text from 1 textField. Off course I only add 1 field.

When I put the JTextField under the for loop I get what I want but how to I get the text from all the JTextFields then? playerNames is then not known in the getter.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In your loop, create the label, the text field, and add an action listener to the text field that will update the value of the corresponding label when the text in the field changes. Add the widgets to your panel and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows, creating a `List`of `JTextField`:

```
JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel();
List<JTextField> playerNames = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

public OptionPlayerNames() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        JTextField playerName = new JTextField();

        playerPanel.add(new JLabel("Player " + (i + 1)));
        playerPanel.add(playerName);

        playerNames.add(playerName);
    }
    playerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(playerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    playerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
}

public JPanel getPanel() {
    return playerPanel;
}

public String getPlayerNames() {
    String output = "";
    // Compound you exit from the playerNames List
    // Or better, return a List of String
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a `Vector` or array of `JTextField` as an instance variable (not just one, as you've commented out) and fill it in as you loop. Then you have random (arbitrary) access to any text value. Conveniently, the index `i` is already there for you to index into the array.

There should be a tip-off that the type: `JTextField` is singular, but your variable name: `playerNames` is plural. :-)

Note that `getPlayerNames()` also needs to be re-done to handle an array not a single field.

While this will work, ultimately, the whole code block isn't good separation of Model & View, so as you advance in programming, be sure to pay attention to that concept.